# C++11 regex details

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

Where can I find details about the new C++11, and in particular (at the moment) the `regex` library?
By details I don't mean how to use, as there seem to be many tutorials out there about that, but rather what exceptions can be thrown and what causes them, which regex syntax is more efficient in what cases, etc.

Answers should include a link, please, not just "Read the spec"!

Comment: Downvote button says "This question does not show any research effort" -- sounds pretty applicable to me!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but part of the downvote description is "question does not show any research effort."

Comment: @ildjarn: It doesn't sound applicable to me. The question is quite specific, and you can't just go to Wikipedia for an answer. Plus, it is evident from the question that the OP has already looked around.

Comment: @Marcelo : _Any_ decent reference will list what exceptions can be thrown and what causes them, and the rest is more-or-less unanswerable.

Comment: @ildjarn I did search. For every term I could think of. All Google found for me was tutorials and examples on how to use it.

Comment: @ildjarn: Then by all means point the way.

Comment: Sounds like the OP has a regex problem he can't solve, blaming it on a language library.

Comment: @sln No problem. I wanted to catch the exceptions so that I can write non-throwing code. I have never read these spec docs before and was a little lost when I couldn't find it where I thought it might be in the spec. I would appreciate it if someone would tell me where it is in the spec.

Comment: @ildjarn I guess there are no decent references out there, since none of them list the exceptions, except for the spec that I can't figure out how to read and where it is in the spec.

Comment: @baruch : [N3337](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) §28 (page 1048), every member function that can throw an exception has a clause titled "_Throws:_" with a description of what would cause it.

Comment: @ildjarn I don't see any member functions there. Member functions of what? Where is it? That is just the main section of regex, which is where I looked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the spec. Here's a link: [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

Comment: Can you please point me to the correct section since it was not where I thought it would be in the spec? I have no experience with this long and very detailed papers, and am lost trying to find it.

Comment: The table of contents is pretty clear. Chapter 28 defines the regex library. To find, e.g., exceptions thrown by regex constructors and what causes them go to chapter 28, section 8, sub-section 2, listed as "basic_regex constructors" in the ToC. It's page 1066 in n3337. As for what regex syntax is most efficient in what cases, don't worry about differences between engines. That's not likely to be documented anywhere anyway. Instead just learn about regex behavior [in general](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/01/regex-performance.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can find reference documentation on [most if not all of C++11's standard library here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex). However:

> which regex syntax is more efficient in what cases, etc.

You're not going to find that anywhere. Each implementation of the C++11 standard library will be *different*. And therefore, what is (slightly) more or less efficient will change from library to library.

Comment: Perhaps regex isin't really language dependent.

Answer (score 0):

There's a cheatsheet here if you are interested in those things, http://cpprocks.com/wp-content/uploads/c++11-regex-cheatsheet.pdf